# System.Diagnostic.Process class works in console application but not work in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, process, console-application

I am running doors.exe using Process class. When I run it in the console application, there is no problem, but the program hangs in the web application. What could be the reason for this?

here is my code below;

```
public string ExecuteDoorsScript(string dxlScriptPath, string userName, string password)
    {

        //Start the process
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe";
        info.Arguments = "-b \"" + dxlScriptPath + "\" -u " + userName + " -P " + password + "-W -d 1234567@databasepath.it";
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    
        var process = Process.Start(info);
        //Wait for the window to finish loading.
        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        //Wait for the process to end.
        process.WaitForExit();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            throw new Exception("Doors run dxl error: " + error);
        }
        return output;
        


    }
```

my dxl script;

```
string topfoldername = "/Test"
void listIndices(Folder parent, int level)
{
Item i
Folder f
for i in parent do {
f = folder(i)
cout << (uniqueID i) ";" (name i) ";" ((type i)) ";" "\n"
}}
listIndices(folder topfoldername, 1)
```

Comment: As a note, you should first wait for the exit and then read standard output.

Comment: The reason it hangs may depend on the script you rün.

Comment: I added my dxl script.